# Learning Assembly and IDA

Tags: assembly, ida

I am trying to learn a little assembly/disassembly.
I created a basic Hello World C EXE(with a simple addition function) and threw it into the free version of IDA.

I sort of see what is going on.  Just to clarify... What does the following do?

```
var_D8= dword ptr -0D8h
var_14= dword ptr -14h
var_8= dword ptr -8
```

It shows three DWORD Variables.  What is -0D8H?  -14H?  -8?
Memory addresses?  I just have it adding 15 + 1.

Sorry I am new to IDA and Assembly.

Thank you

Comment: IDA couldn't figure it out either so it just made a gimpy declaration for it.  Probably used as an offset from EBP, a local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDA create special structure for describing stack of current functions. Address of places in this structure are offsets from return address (that saves in stack too, and mentioned as "r" in stack view window). And this defines are simple offsets from it. Compilers save into stack local variables and it is representation of variables on stack. Read IDA Pro book for more details on this topic.